# MacOS keybindings not overriden inside VS Code debugger?

Tags: python, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently using VSCode Version 1.28.2 (1.28.2). When I use the integrated debugger, I find that the F11 key (whose purpose is to step into a function) does not override the MacOS (Sierra 10.12.6) default behaviour (show Desktop). I'm currently bypassing the issue by disabling the shortcut on my Mac, but this seems like a sub-par fix. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not a macOS user but generally speaking I don't think applications can "override" OS-level shortcuts. Instead, the OS sees key presses first and decides what to do with them. If they're meaningful to the OS they often won't be passed to the application. If Visual Studio Code never _sees_ the keypress it can't do anything with it.

Comment: use system preferences > keyboard > shortcuts > app shortcuts to add the corresponding menu shortcut to vs code

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the `fn` key when you press F11 and it will then act as F11 and not "Show Desktop".

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS:

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and uncheck the "Show Desktop F11" option inside one of the submenus (Mission Control).

This worked for me on

Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: after so many years of clicking Step Into with the mouse... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fluor](https://fluorapp.net). It can automatically enable the Function keys depending on the current application in view.

This lets you use F11, and other function keys in VS Code while automatically switching back to the default functions when in other apps.